# Using getScript on multiple jQuery game files, but they don't seem to be loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working through a game-making tutorial and trying to load my different jquery files, but they don't seem to be working. Here's an abbreviated version of my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function getScripts(scripts, callback) {
  var progress = 0;
   var internalCallback = function () {
    if (++progress == scripts.length) { callback(); }
};

scripts.forEach(function(script) { $.getScript(script, internalCallback); });
};

getScripts(["_js/ui.js", "_js/bubble.js", "_js/game.js"], function () {
 function();
  $(function(){
   var game = new BubbleShoot.Game();
   game.init();
 })
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="start_game" class="dialog">
<div id="start_game_message">
 <h2>Start a new game</h2>
</div>
<div class="but_start_game button">
 New Game
</div>
</body>
```

And then I've got three pretty basic jQuery files:
ui.js

```
var BubbleShoot = window.BubbleShoot || {};
BubbleShoot.ui = (function($){
 var ui = {
  init : function(){
  },
  hideDialog : function(){
   $(".dialog").fadeOut(300);
  }
 };
 return ui;
})(jQuery);
```

bubble.js

```
var BubbleShoot = window.BubbleShoot || {};
 BubbleShoot.Bubble = (function($){
var Bubble = function(sprite){
 var that = this;
  this.getSprite = function(){return sprite;};
};
 Bubble.create = function(){
var sprite = $(document.createElement ("div"));
 sprite.addClass("bubble");
 sprite.addClass("bubble_0");
 var bubble = new Bubble(sprite);
 return bubble;
};
return Bubble;
})(jQuery);
```

and game.js

```
BubbleShoot.Game = (function($){
 var Game = function(){
  var curBubble;
   this.init = function(){
  $(".but_start_game").bind("click",startGame);
};
var startGame = function(){
 $(".but_start_game").unbind("click");
 BubbleShoot.ui.hideDialog();
 curBubble = getNextBubble();
};
var getNextBubble = function(){
 var bubble = BubbleShoot.Bubble.create();
 bubble.getSprite().addClass("cur_bubble");
 $("#board").append(bubble.getSprite());
 return bubble;
};
};
 return Game;
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried loading the scripts individually or loading them in the body of the file, but they just don't appear to be working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing `function();` at callback of `getScripts` ?

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't appear to be working?

Comment: Can you describe _" still doesn't appear to be working"_ ? , reproduce at stacksnippets , plnkr http://plnkr.co ?

Comment: Your scripting is more advanced than mine, but I will try... Firstly, I would place your declarations after your functions (thus put _var BubbleShoot = window.BubbleShoot || {};_ as the last line in _bubble.js_). If that does not work, I would place _console.log("test");_ calls in each of your three external scripts and have them sit outside any function. This should indicate if any execution takes place. Lastly, like guest user above said earlier, describe "still doesn't appear to be working". Does your console show that ajax calls are being made?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner—part of the issue seems to have been my test server, but removing function() did end up making ui.js work properly. I checked execution on bubble.js and game.js and they're now loading correctly as well, but my test server is once again breaking. Thanks so much for the help as I've sorted this out!